# How can I use inner join like this I dont understand it

Tags: sql, join

So the question ask to get some database from two table and I looked to the code he used inner join
the code is:

```
SELECT
  first_name,
  last_name,
  count(*) as admissions_total
from admissions a
  join doctors ph on ph.doctor_id = a.attending_doctor_id
group by attending_doctor_id
```

So the question is what `ph` he used and `a`. I don't get it how its inner join where the two table don't have same attribute

I try to get left join or right join but will not solve it

Comment: `ph` and `a` are aliases for the tables.  you could also write it as:  `FROM admissions AS a` and `JOIN doctors AS ph`.  it's shorthand for `doctors.doctor_id = admissions.attending_doctor_id` so you don't have to write out the entire table name multiple times and can just reference the [alias](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/alias.php).

Comment: It's not clear from your question why you would want to use left join or right join.  We don't know anything about your data or desired result set.  It appears from the query, that `attending_doctor_id` is the id of the doctor, which is `doctor_id` in the `doctors` table.